# Google search and chrome not working on mobile data

Tags: google, mobile-data, oneplus-one, greenify

I have a OnePlus One on which I am running 5.1.1 Cyanogen OS. I rooted it and installed Greenify, and tried to greenify the google apps. Since then, my google apps are not working over mobile data, but working on wifi. Can anyone please help!? I have unrooted and flashed the factory image but still no good.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and requested a new configuration sms from my mobile carrier. Installed the settings for 0.1 sec, restarted the phone. SOLVED !!!

Answer (score 0):

Figured the issue. Somehow the APN got changed to some other network and that was causing the problem. Not Greenify, though this happened after that.

Comment: The ROM itself is buggy. There are many similar threads discussing the same issue. I installed the ROM from scratch and the same issue occurred to me (no app worked on mobile data). I got frustrated by it, not to mention by some  other stupid bugs, so reverted back to COS12. Many users have  mentioned that resetting the APN and then choosing the correct one helped them.

Answer (score -1):

Just creating dummy APN helped me.

Comment: It will be better if you will include steps to create dummy APN.

Answer (score -1):

I have solve a fix  this issue.

Somehow, the defaults would have a value for the Proxy IP and Port. 
1_Go to setting> network setting>mobile network> Access point settings and delete the Proxy IP 
and Port and save this setting.

Comment: Remove that tel number or get a downvote and a flag.